# How to change font size mid document?

Tags: fonts

I want to create a TeX document for which the first (summary) page is `\documentclass[10pt]{article}`, but for which the rest of the document is `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You mean a LaTeX document, right?

Comment: I deleted an answer of mine containing an untested (and unrecommended) hack that didn't work (because it loaded a file using `\newcommand` on commands already defined). My thanks to Thorsten Donig, who apparently bothered to test it.

Comment: As mentioned in the discussion at [Change line spacing inside the document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83855/change-line-spacing-inside-the-document/), you should explain why [LaTeX — specify font point size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48276) did not provide an adequate solution.  The best way would be to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that illustrates how the linked question did not provide a solution.  Basically show what you tried to do that failed.

Comment: \fontsize{size}{skip}:: \baselineskip but i don't understand its role ?

Answer (score 114):

You can change font size using `\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont` (the first number is the pt size of the font, the second number the space in pts between lines: this becomes the value of `\baselineskip`), but in general I think it's better to try using things like `\tiny`, `\small`, `\scriptsize`, `\normalsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge` and `\Huge`  (and the corresponding environments  (e.g., `\begin{small} ... \end{small}`). I think `\footnotesize` would give you a 10pt font in a document with 12pt set in its document class options.

And if the summary page is done using a special environment, like `\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}` likely what you want can be done a completely different way, such as by using the [abstract](http://ctan.org/pkg/abstract) package. (It's hard to give concrete advice without knowing more about the details of the summary page, however.)

Answer (score 29):

The following will locally reconfigure everything as if a different size agrument had been given to the document class. I assume not every setting will be effective though. But at least all the sizing macros will be appropriately redefined.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{localsize}[1]
{%
  \clearpage
  \let\orignewcommand\newcommand
  \let\newcommand\renewcommand
  \makeatletter
  \input{bk#1.clo}%
  \makeatother
  \let\newcommand\orignewcommand
}
{%
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{localsize}{10}
  \lipsum
\end{localsize}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** This is based on loading the original size definitions of the `book` class named `bk10.clo`, `bk11.clo`, `bk12.clo`, so `10`, `11`, `12` are the possible arguments, corresponding to the options `10pt`, `11pt`, `12pt` of the document class.

For using with another class (for instance `article`), the prefix `bk` used in

```
  \input{bk#1.clo}%
```

needs to be replaced by the one used by the respective class (for instance `size`). Some classes like `memoir` support a wider range of sizes.

Comment: The use of `\clearpage` is perhaps preferred, but not necessary.

Comment: Might be a good idea to add a matching `makeatother`. I guess since it is in an environment it is in a group, but still better to be explicit (IMHO).

Comment: @Mico Good point. Edtited.

Comment: @Werner As some page-specific parameters like `\headheight` are set in the `.clo` files I think using a complete range of pages is better. I've not tested whether everything works as expected though ;-)

Comment: @PeterGrill I *did* have the feeling I'd forgotten to close something ;-) Edited, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @StephanLehmke How about for the **scrreprt** class please? What to replace **bk** with?

Comment: As https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213836/change-in-font-size-from-slide-to-slide refers to this question, I tried this solution, replacing `bk` by `size` as used by the `beamer` package but then I get `Can be used only in preamble.` (when it encounters `NeedsTeXFormat` in `size9.clo`?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig: Right, it's been years, but to answer your question: `size9.clo` is an "extended" size (read, nonstandard).  It works well, but if you `diff` it with say `size10.clo`, you'll see that the only difference (beyond expected stuff dealing with font size) is that `NeedsTeXFormat` command.  Copy the file locally, remove that line, and you'll be all set.

Comment: I've been using this solution with latex, and it works, but today I wanted to convert my .tex to a .odt using pandoc, and I got the following error: `[WARNING] Could not load include file 'bk10.clo.tex'`

Answer (score 12):

If you are using a [KOMA-Script class](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) you can change the basic font size inside the document:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\parbox[t]{.5\textwidth}{%
  \section*{10pt}
  \raggedright
  \tiny tiny\par
  \scriptsize scriptsize\par
  \footnotesize footnotesize\par
  \small small\par
  \normalsize normalsize\par
  \large large\par
  \Large Large\par
  \LARGE LARGE\par
  \huge huge\par
  \Huge Huge\par
}%
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=12pt}
\parbox[t]{.5\textwidth}{%
  \section*{12pt}
  \raggedright
  \tiny tiny\par
  \scriptsize scriptsize\par
  \footnotesize footnotesize\par
  \small small\par
  \normalsize normalsize\par
  \large large\par
  \Large Large\par
  \LARGE LARGE\par
  \huge huge\par
  \Huge Huge\par
}
\end{document}
```

[image: KOMA-Script example]

If you are not using a KOMA-Script class, you can use the KOMA-Script package `scrextend`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\begin{document}
\parbox[t]{.5\textwidth}{%
  \section*{10pt}
  \raggedright
  \tiny tiny\par
  \scriptsize scriptsize\par
  \footnotesize footnotesize\par
  \small small\par
  \normalsize normalsize\par
  \large large\par
  \Large Large\par
  \LARGE LARGE\par
  \huge huge\par
  \Huge Huge\par
}%
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=12pt}
\parbox[t]{.5\textwidth}{%
  \section*{12pt}
  \raggedright
  \tiny tiny\par
  \scriptsize scriptsize\par
  \footnotesize footnotesize\par
  \small small\par
  \normalsize normalsize\par
  \large large\par
  \Large Large\par
  \LARGE LARGE\par
  \huge huge\par
  \Huge Huge\par
}
\end{document}
```

[image: standard class example]

Caveat: Not all length depending on the basic font size will be changed, if you use `\KOMAoptions{fontsize=…}`. For example, if a package uses code like

```
 \newlength{\foo}
 \setlength{\foo}{2\baselineskip}
```

length `\foo` will not be influenced by the change of `fontsize`. So using option `fontsize` inside the document (or even in the document preamble) is not the exactly the same like using `10pt`, `11pt`, `12pt` or `fontsize` as optional argument of `\documentclass`. It is only more or less close to it.

Answer (score 9):

A ConTeXt solution:

- If you want the footnotes, headers and footers, etc in the first page to correspond to 10pt and rest of the document to correspond to 12pt:

```
\setupbodyfont[10pt]
\starttext
Abstract
\page
\setupbodyfont[12pt]
....
\stoptext
```

- If you want all the footnotes, headers and footnotes, etc. to correspond to 12pt font size

```
\setupbodyfont[12pt]
\starttext
\start
\switchtobodyfont[10pt]
Abstract: ...
\stop
\page
Rest of the document
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 4):

If the normal size is 12pt, the text enclosed in the group will be in 10pt. The text size of the header and the footer will keep unaltered.

```
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\input{first_page_content.tex}
\endgroup
\clearpage
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way would be to create a 10pt document for the summary and include its pdf output within the 12pt document. You could use the `pdfpages` package for that purpose.

If you really wish to use just one document, you could redefine `\normalsize` and all the other size macros like `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize` etc. you can find the definition inside the `.clo` files like size10.clo.

But I would choose the easier way, splitting the document code.