# LaTeX -- specify font point size?

Tags: fontsize

I want to use a font size other than the standard LaTeX list of tiny, huge, etc.  How can I do that?

Comment: Related Question: [Change font size inside the document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87905/change-font-size-inside-the-document).

Answer (score 119, accepted):

From `info latex`:

> `\fontsize{size}{skip}`
>        Set font size. The first parameter is the font size to switch to;
>        the second is the `\baselineskip` to use. The unit of both
>        parameters defaults to pt. A rule of thumb is that the
>        baselineskip should be 1.2 times the font size.

As @frabjous noted, you'll need to add `\selectfont` afterwards to make it kick in.

Comment: You'll need to add `\selectfont` afterwards to make it kick in.

Comment: Thanks . . . that works . . . but now my superscript is in the new size (not made smaller).  Is there a way to tell it to keep it proportional?

Comment: Also, the baseline skip doesn't seem to do anything.  It ends up that the top of the text of each line is at basically the same place as the bottom of the previous line . . . maybe a tiny bit lower, but certainly not sensible line spacing.

Comment: @William: See [Fonts at arbitrary sizes](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=fontsize) and [Other "document font" sizes?](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=extsizes).

Comment: Also, it has to be within the `document` tags, not in the preamble.

Comment: It seems not works correctly with fontspec?

Answer (score 28):

There are a couple of LaTeX packages available that provide for additional font sizes:

The [`moresize`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moresize) package offers additional commands to have a broader range (`\HUGE`, `\ssmall`), whereas [`extsizes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) extends the standard LaTeX classes by additional class options (`8pt`, ... `20pt` for the base font, so that all fonts in the document become smaller or bigger, but remain their relative difference. Advanced document classes (memoir, but especially the KOMA-Skript bundle) provide built-in capabilities for flexible font sizes.