# Is there a way to set the font size in points?

Tags: fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX — specify font point size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48276/latex-specify-font-point-size)

I'm working with beamer and one of my headlines is too big if I use `\Large`, and too small if I use `\large`. I'd like it to be just right. Is there a way to set the font size in absolute values, i.e. in points (`pt`) or something like that?

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48276) is also of interest for you.

Comment: I'd say my question is a duplicate of this one :) I did search but did not find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{3cm}{3.2cm}\selectfont abc
\end{document}
```