# Why does fontspec not handle setting the font size in points?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, fontsize, points

I would like to set the exact size, in points, of a font in my TeX document. Perusing through the `fontspec` documentation, I did not find a lot of information related to setting the font size. So I turned to google. Several posts suggest using `\fontsize` combined with `\selectfont`, including:

- [How to change section/subsection font size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103286/how-to-change-section-subsection-font-size)
- [LaTeX -- specify font point size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48276/latex-specify-font-point-size)
- [Is there a way to set the font size in points?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57195/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-font-size-in-points)

My question is twofold:

- Why does `fontspec` not handle this?
- Where do `\fontsize` and `\selectfont` come from? Are the LaTeX primitives? Are they part of a library?

Comment: why should fontspec do something here? \fontsize and \selectfont are the right commands for this and they are already defined by LaTeX.

Comment: “Font size” is not a well-defined quantity. Times at 10pt is quite different in size from, say, Lucida at 10pt.

Comment: Do `texdoc latex2e` for the documentation for the font commands, especially section 4 "Fonts". `fontspec` package deals with handling font features (face, weight, shape, scale, script, language, faces for specific sizes, OTF font feature switches, etc) and being able to use system fonts. `unicode-math` package builds on top of that for math, and `polyglossia` (for example) builds on top of that for multi/poly-lingual typesetting purposes. And so on.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer could you please tell me more about `\fontsize` and `selectfont`? Which library do they belong to? Are they native commands?

Comment: I already wrote: LaTeX defines them, that means the format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked, "Where do `\fontsize` and `\selectfont` come from? Are the[y] LaTeX primitives? Are they part of a library?"

- Both macros are defined by the LaTeX2e kernel, or *format*. The term "primitive" [command] has a special meaning in TeX and LaTeX circles, so it's not wise to call `\fontsize` and `\selectfont` "primitives".
- Just as the original "Plain TeX" *format* consists of a set of primitives (frequently, but not universally, referred to as "Knuth TeX") and a set of macros that build on these primitives (both the primitives and the aforementioned macros are explained in full detail in the TeXbook), the LaTeX2e *format* consists of a set of primitives (which these days come from eTeX, not Knuth TeX) and a set of macros defined in the LaTeX2e kernel. The LaTeX kernel may be found in the file `latex.ltx`.
- In the current version of `latex.ltx` ("LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1"), the macro `\fontsize` is defined on lines 7036 and 7037 of the file, as follows:

  ```
  \DeclareRobustCommand\fontsize[2]
     {\set@fontsize\baselinestretch{#1}{#2}}
  ```

  The macro `\set@fontsize` is defined on lines 7985 thru 8002 as follows:

  ```
  \def\set@fontsize#1#2#3{%
      \@defaultunits\@tempdimb#2pt\relax\@nnil
      \edef\f@size{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}%
      \@defaultunits\@tempskipa#3pt\relax\@nnil
      \edef\f@baselineskip{\the\@tempskipa}%
      \edef\f@linespread{#1}%
      \let\baselinestretch\f@linespread
        \def\size@update{%
          \baselineskip\f@baselineskip\relax
          \baselineskip\f@linespread\baselineskip
          \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip
          \setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
            \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
                  \@depth.3\baselineskip
                  \@width\z@}%
          \let\size@update\relax}%
    }
  ```
- The macro `\selectfont`, in turn, is defined on lines 7954 thru 7985 as follows:

  ```
  \DeclareRobustCommand\selectfont
          {%
      \ifx\f@linespread\baselinestretch \else
        \set@fontsize\baselinestretch\f@size\f@baselineskip \fi
      \ifx\delayed@f@adjustment\@empty
      \else
        \let\f@shape@saved\f@shape
        \let\f@series@saved\f@series
        \delayed@f@adjustment
        \maybe@load@fontshape
        \ifcsname \f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/\f@shape \endcsname
        \else
          \let\f@shape\f@shape@saved
          \let\f@series\f@series@saved
          \let\delayed@merge@font@shape\merge@font@shape
          \let\delayed@merge@font@series\merge@font@series
          \delayed@f@adjustment
          \let\delayed@merge@font@shape\merge@font@shape@without@substitution
          \let\delayed@merge@font@series\merge@font@series@without@substitution
        \fi
        \let\delayed@f@adjustment\@empty
      \fi
      \@forced@seriesfalse
      \xdef\font@name{%
        \csname\curr@fontshape/\f@size\endcsname}%
      \pickup@font
      \font@name
      \UseHook{selectfont}%
      \size@update
      \enc@update
      }
  \NewHook{selectfont}
  ```
- As the code demonstrates, both macros are quite complex and rely on a sizable number of subsidiary macros to get much of their work done.
- You also asked, "Why does `fontspec` not handle this?" As @UlrikeFischer and @Cicada have already pointed out in comments, there's no need or justifiable reason for making `fontspec` perform tasks that are handled perfectly well by the existing LaTeX macros `\fontsize` and `\selectfont`.

Comment: This is already beyond my current level of understanding by I do see myself returning to your valuable answer in the near future and understanding more of it as my abilities in LaTeX improve. I trust it is complete and therefore accept it.