# Set fixed font size in floating tables with floatrow package

Tags: fontsize, floatrow

The [floatrow](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package allows global changes to the font size in floating tables with commands such as `font = small` (cf. section 3.1.2 of the [documentation)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf). But such settings only change the *relative* size of the font.

In some cases, as in [Change font inside document to specific point size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145785/change-font-inside-document-to-specific-point-size), the font size needs to be fixed rather than relative. How can I set a fixed size for my floating tables with `floatrow`? Borrowing from the solution to the linked question above, I tried just specifying `\floatsetup{font = {doublespacing, \fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}}`, but this only resulted in an error.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, setspace}
    \doublespacing
\usepackage{floatrow}
    \floatplacement{table}{hbtp}
    \floatsetup{font = doublespacing}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{*4{l}}
        A & B & C & D\\
        x & w & y & z\\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a "caption font":

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\DeclareCaptionFont{Small}{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
\floatsetup{font={doublespacing,Small}}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be ``DeclareFloatFont``? I don't want to fiddle with the font in the captions.

Comment: `Caption` belongs to the package name , not to the `\caption`

Comment: The documentation prefers ``\DeclareFloatFont``, though (section 3.6.2), and I think that name is less confusing than ``\DeclareCaptionFont``. But it adds that "This macro works like ``\DeclareCaptionFont`` in ``caption`` package: you may also use key options declared by ``\DeclareCaptionFont`` command."