# Set line spacing to point size

Tags: line-spacing

These are the recommendations of the [`setspace`](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/setspace/setspace.sty) package:

> If a different spacing is required [than `\singlespacing`,
>   `\onehalfspacing`, or `\doublespacing`] then the
>   `\setstretch{baselinestretch}` command can be used in the preamble to
>   set the baselinestretch appropriately.

`\baselinestretch` scales the value of `\baselineskip`, and it is generally [recommended not to change the value of `\baselineskip` itself](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/latex/baselineskip.html).

So say that I need to set my document with an `11pt` font with `12pt` line spacing. Rather than just telling LaTeX to use `12pt` spacing, the "recommended" way is to perform some math to figure out the appropriate factor of `\baselineskip`, like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \setstretch{.88235}
\begin{document}
\the\baselineskip % gives 12.00002pt
\end{document}
```

Clearly there must be a better way? I'm [reminded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145785/change-font-inside-document-to-specific-point-size) of the `\fontsize{size}{skip}` command, where you could just say `\fontsize{11}{12}`, but as far as I know, this is intended for temporary changes to the font size and line spacing, and not to be used as a preamble setting for the entire document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look what the standard classes do here, in `size11.clo` you see

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xipt{13.6}%
   \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
```

which sets up `\normalsize` to be `10.95pt` on `13.6pt`, if you want `11bp` on `12bp` just redefine it to be

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{11bp}{12bp}%
   \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
```

and any other adjustments you need.

Comment: This is the simplest way? It baffles my why there is such a simple `\fontsize{size}{skip}` command for a temporary font size change, but nothing like that for a permanent change.

Comment: @Sverre `\fontsize` is permanent if you do not enclose it in a group, but setting `\normalsize` is, as you see, more than just setting the default font and baselineskip, it makes sense to specify other dependent lengths at the same time. Of course you do not _have_ to do that  but then when some figure or whatever issues \normalsize to get into a standard state, less things are reset.

Comment: Gotcha! So all those other settings in `size11.clo` (those with `displayshortskip` etc.) should not be affected by changing the linespacing?

Comment: @Sverre they would not be affected if you just set baselineskip, so if you were in a \large area and then do `\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont...` the text would go back to 11pt  but any equations would have lots of space, `\normalsize` tries to ensure everything put back to normal.

Comment: I just noticed your use of big point `bp` rather than the TeX point `pt`. You probably assumed that the people who want me to set these point sizes have big points in mind? I don't think they have any idea about the difference `:)`

Comment: @Sverre even if they don't care, you have the option of giving them what they asked for:-)