# line spacing broken by \begin{english}

Tags: luatex, line-spacing, polyglossia

I am trying to produce an A4 page for our doors. I have used LuaLaTeX. In the spirit of exploration, I tried to use `\begin{czech}` and `\begin{english}` from polyglossia package. The MWE is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape,oneside]{minimal}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{czech}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{czech}
\fontsize{1.5cm}{1em}\selectfont
\textsc{Až projdete, \textbf{otočte} se a ujistěte se, že jsou \textbf{dveře \underline{úplně zavřené}}.} \\
\end{czech}
\hrule
\begin{english}
\fontsize{1.5cm}{1em}\selectfont
\textsc{After you walk through, \textbf{turn around} and make sure the \textbf{door is \underline{completely closed}}.}
\end{english}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The resulting document looks like this:

[image: result]

Notice how the line spacing is different for the English message part. Commenting out the polyglossia language selections fixes the result for me.

Why is using the `\begin{english}` breaking the line spacing and how can I avoid it / fix it?

**UPDATE**

It appears that `1em` is not accepted format of the size for the `\fontsize` macro. Using `1.8cm` works and fixes the issue.

Comment: You are using a much too small baselineskip (1em). Use something like `\fontsize{1.5cm}{1.8cm}\selectfont`. And add a `\par` before closing the language environments. The czech is faulty too but there the accents forces the lines more apart.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `english`. Leave the `\fontsize` and the exglish text and you will see the same thing. Not sure why, but it is a bit odd to have a line spacing that is smaller than the font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the fontsize is the culprit here. See the proposed change below. I have added a \vspace{1em} to create some more distance between the underline and the separating line and before the English part. Drop either one of these if it suits you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape,oneside]{minimal}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{czech}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{czech}
\fontsize{20mm}{24mm}\selectfont
\textsc{Až projdete, \textbf{otočte} se a ujistěte se, že jsou \textbf{dveře \underline{úplně zavřené}}.} \\
\end{czech}
\vspace{20mm}
\hrule
\vspace{1em}
\begin{english}
\fontsize{20mm}{24mm}\selectfont
\textsc{After you walk through, \textbf{turn around} and make sure the \textbf{door is \underline{completely closed}}.}
\end{english}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this is is a good solution. Setting a baselineskip of 1em with a font size of 2cm is wrong, because the interline spacing will be uneven.

Comment: Would you suggest that using \vspace{some fixed distance} would be better? Such as \vspace{18mm}?

Comment: You misunderstand how [`\fontsize` works](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48277/8528): the second argument does not "add" extra space to the top of the first argument.

Comment: @jon, thanks for the help. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have several errors in your example code.

1. You should never set the baselineskip less than the font size for typesetting a paragraph, or the spacing between lines will be uneven.
2. You should set the font size in the whole `center` environment.
3. Before and after the `\hrule` some vertical space is needed.
4. You should never use the `minimal` class.

Here's a fixed version, you might want to adjust the baselineskip.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fix-cm} % for avoiding spurious error messages

\setdefaultlanguage{czech}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{1.5cm}{1.8cm}\selectfont

\begin{czech}
Až projdete, \textbf{otočte} se a ujistěte se,
že jsou \textbf{dveře \underline{úplně zavřené}}.\\
\end{czech}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\begin{english}
After you walk through, \textbf{turn around} and make
sure the \textbf{door is \underline{completely closed}}.
\end{english}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I removed `\textsc` because the Latin Modern fonts don't have bold small caps.

[image]