# Change line spacing inside the document

Tags: line-spacing

This is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\begin{document}
\include{Chapter1}
\end{document}
```

I have please a question:

I would change the line spacing (1.5 --> 1.0) of a page inside the document and not the entire document and the size of the words, how can I do please?

Comment: after using your code my chapters start being displayed on the left side (which is odd and wrong) - how can I make latex display them on the right (also known as the right) side again? I'm using the {book} class.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can use `\setstretch{}`. If you want to only affect a certain content you can use it with a group.

[image]

You can also apply any size changing switches such as `\small` or `\tiny` inside the `{}` group as well.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
{\setstretch{1.0}\color{blue}
\lipsum[2]
}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just remember to end the paragraph before the final `}` (`\lipsum` adds a `\par` at its end). Using `\linespread{1.5}` (or some command of `setspace`) is better than redefining `\baselinestretch`.

Comment: @Peter Thank you so much :) Please i have another question: i have used \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}  and i'd like to change the size 12 to 10 of one paragraph inside the document, Have you an idea please ?

Comment: @researcher: You could try using the answers from [LaTeX — specify font point size?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48276/latex-specify-font-point-size) and keep the change to be within a group (either inside a brace group `{}`, or within `\begingroup`, `\endgroup` pair. If that does not help you achieve the desired results you should post a separate question.  Also, please note that you should use the full username with the `@` syntax. I was only notified of this as it was a comment to an answer of mine.

Comment: i set \fontsize{10} just before the text ?

Comment: @researcher: `fontsize` has two parameters, not one.

Comment: yes it's \baselineskip but i don't understand its role ?

Comment: @researcher: As this discussion is _not_ related to "line spacing" which is what this question is about, please post a new question. You should reference any questions that are relevant in this new question.

Comment: Change line spacing of a page and size police inside the document--> its mentionned in the title, i should ask in a new discussion ?

Comment: @researcher: Yes I see that is mentioned in the title, but I would suggest you change this title to remove that and post a separate question regarding font size. That way it is more likely to be helpful to others as the two questions should be easier to find.  And, you should also reference the question I linked to and explain why that did not solve your issue. The best way would be to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that illustrates how the linked question did not provide a solution.

Comment: Very nice and neat solution. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I know this is an old answer but the given code does not produce the desired output. No change in linespacing. Is `setspace` depreciated? Or is there some problem on my end? Using MacTeX current installation with TeXshop version 4.64.

Comment: @SandyG:  Seems to work for me with TeXLive 2021. Don't think the version of TeXShop is related, but mine is 4.67.  I suggest you post a new question, include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. Also, you may want to use `\listfiles` to display the version info and include that in the question. I suspect something is out of date for you.

Comment: It's not working for me with TexLive 2021 either. I'm using it inside a Minipage. Is it supposed to be that way (not working inside a minipage)? BTW, `\linespread{}` is not working either.

Comment: @Andyc: Seems to work for me inside a `minipage` with TeXLive 2021. I suggest you post a new question and include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem. Also, include a `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}`. This will output the versions of the pacakges and including that in your question will help to determine if some of your packages are not up to date.

Answer (score 34):

Alternatively, the following solution is a bit cleaner:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing % Set line spacing to 1.5

\lipsum[1]

\singlespacing % Reset line spacing to 1 from here on
\lipsum[2]
\onehalfspacing % Reset line spacing to 1.5 from here on

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

For other values, you can use e.g. `\setstretch{1.125}` instead of `\singlespacing` and `\onehalfspacing`.

The advantage of this method is that you don't need a closing statement, such as `end{}` or a curly bracket.

Comment: It looks like this also works (on Overleaf, at least) without adding the package `setspace`.

Answer (score 28):

## Other values

Other line spacing values that lie in between `onehalf`, `single` and `double` can also be achieved with:

```
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{spacing}{1.125}
…
\end{spacing}
```

Comment: Note that this solution increases the spacing of **all** lines, if you have e.g. 2 lines, both will have the spacing of 1.125

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redefining `\baselinestretch`, you can set a new value to `\linespread` and apply the changes with `\selectfont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\linespread{1.0}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.

\linespread{2.5}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.

\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.

\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

A friendly reminder for everyone using the `memoir` class that it provides its own mechanisms for line spacing:

```
\begin{Spacing}{0.9}
      tightly spaced text
\end{Spacing}
```

There are also `SingleSpace`, `OnehalfSpace` and `DoubleSpace` environments;
starred versions of those that do not automatically add `\vskip\baselineskip` at the end;
various crutches to fine-tune everything; etc.
Take a look at p. 51 of `texdoc memoir`.