# change space to only a part of the document

Tags: spacing, setspace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change line spacing of a page and size police inside the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83855/change-line-spacing-of-a-page-and-size-police-inside-the-document)

I created a document using `book` class and set the space using

```
\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing
```

In this way all my document use this setting.

Instead  I would know how I change space to `\doublespacing` to only a part of my document.

Answer (score 11):

You could type `\begin{doublespacing}` and `\end{doublespacing}` at that beginning and at the end of the part of your document that you want to be double-spaced.

Answer (score 2):

You can use them inside a group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
 \lipsum[1]
\bgroup %% <<<<<<< begin a group
\doublespacing
\lipsum[2]
\egroup %% <<<<<<< end a group
{   %% <<<<<<< begin a group
\singlespacing
\lipsum[3]
} %% <<<<<<< end a group
\end{document}
```