# Declaration commands of setspace have no effect inside groups

Tags: line-spacing, grouping, setspace

According to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84395/18401) of the question [change space to only a part of the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84391/18401) (about 8 years ago), the effect of `setspace`' declaration commands (`\singlespacing`, `\onehalfspacing`, `\doublespacing`) should be limited by groups.

But the following MCE shows that:

- outside groups, these commands have the expected effect.
- inside groups, these commands have... **no effect!**

Do you know why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace,lipsum,xcolor}
% Paragraphs in red:              in single spacing.
% Paragraphs in blue: (should be) in double spacing.
\begin{document}
\footnotesize % In order to get a single page.

% Single spacing is the default.
\color{red}
\lipsum[1]

% \doublespacing outside a group switches to double spacing.
\doublespacing
\color{blue}
\lipsum[1]

% Back to default: \singlespacing outside a group switches to single spacing.
\singlespacing
\color{red}
\lipsum[1]

% \doublespacing inside a group DOESN'T switch to double spacing.
{% %% <<<<<<< begin a group
  \doublespacing
  \color{blue}
  \lipsum[1]
} %% <<<<<<< end a group

% \doublespacing inside a group DOESN'T switch to double spacing.
\bgroup %% <<<<<<< begin a group
  \doublespacing
  \color{blue}
  \lipsum[1]
\egroup %% <<<<<<< end a group
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A paragraph is set using the setting *at the end of a paragraph* so leave a blank  line before the closing `}` otherwise the settings are lost before the paragraph ends.

This is most commonly seen with size commands like `\large` where the font change happens at the point of the declaration but the associated change of baselineskip only happens if the paragraph ends in the same scope.

Comment: Sigh... I'm always falling into the same trap!