# Customizing apacite style using bibtex in SWP

Tags: bibtex

Sorry for the basic question, but I got stuck finishing up my thesis. I'm using Scientific Workplace 5.5 (very basic LaTeX literacy) and I need to customize `apacite` to meet the faculty requirements.

I need to:

1. be able to customize the .bbl file and deal with capitalization problems,
2. create a "numbered" reference list,
3. modify the spacing between lines.

Even if I edit the `.bbl` file using Notepad++, nothing changes in my output PDF file.

I am not sure where to add any necessary codes to introduce numbering as I'm using SWP.

Here is a sample of my `.bbl` file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}


\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{%
  C. Capps}{%
  C. Capps}{%
  2010}]{%
  Capp10b}%
  \APACinsertmetastar{%
    Capp10b}%
  Capps, C. \newblock{}\BBOP{}2010, June\BBCP{}. \newblock{}\BBOQ{}Buyer power in health plan mergers.\BBCQ{} \newblock{}\Bem{Journal of Competition Law and Economics}, \Bem{6}(2), 375-391.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{%
  C. Capps \BBA{} Dranove}{%
  C. Capps \BBA{} Dranove}{%
  2004}]{%
  Capp04}%
  \APACinsertmetastar{%
    Capp04}%
  Capps, C.\BCBT{} \BBA{} Dranove, D. \newblock{}\BBOP{}2004, March\BBCP{}. \newblock{}\BBOQ{}Hospital consolidation and negotiated ppo prices.\BBCQ{} \newblock{}\Bem{Health Affairs}(2), 175-181.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Here is what my preamble in SWP looks like:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition} \newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\geometry{left=1.378in,right=0.984in,top=0.984in,bottom=0.984in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.25in}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\widowpenalty=50000000
\clubpenalty=50000000
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `biblatex` with option `style=apa`? It's relatively easy to customise if one doesn't have too many modifications to do.

Comment: I am not sure what question 1 means, but see [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/23160). For question 2, [enumerate bibliography items](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199577/23160) may be helpful. For question 3, a possible LaTeX solution would be to [use `\setstretch` from the `setspace` package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83856/23160), although I have no if and how raw LaTeX code is to be used in Scientific WorkPlace documents. Making changes to `.bbl` files is error-prone because the changes will be overwritten if `bibtex` is run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned that working with an online tex editor solves all these problems. I prefer writelatex as it simultaneously provides a preview, hence it's impossible to create a mess with the codes. As it is an online service there is no need to find and download every single additional package, so I can use the alternatives Bernard and mvkorpel adviced above.