# enumerate bibliography items

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I'm using `bibtex`, the package `apacite` and

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{tesis}
```

I'm sorting the bibliography aphabetically (author-year) and everyting's ok except that I want to enumerate the bibliography items (just in the bibliography). I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24501/biblatex-enumerating-sorted-bibliography-using-authoryear-ibid-style), but it's for `biblatex` and I can't make it work in my case. Any help will be apreciated!

Comment: Please provide a full (but minimal) example document with two sample references in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following solution I use a new counter for numeric labels. The internal command `\@biblabel` is redefined to increment and print the counter. It gets called at the beginning of each item. The space after the numeric labels can be adjusted with `\biblabelsep`. See the [manual of apacite](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf) for some documentation on the customization facilities.

[image: Output of example code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0.3em}
\newcounter{MyBibCount}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\stepcounter{MyBibCount}\theMyBibCount.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\nocite{article-minimal}\nocite{inbook-minimal}
\nocite{book-minimal}\nocite{incollection-minimal}
\nocite{mastersthesis-minimal}\nocite{inproceedings-minimal}
\nocite{whole-proceedings}\nocite{phdthesis-minimal}
\nocite{techreport-full}\nocite{unpublished-minimal}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```