# Why does changing \baselinestretch not change line spacing?

Tags: lengths

I have read that line spacing in a LaTeX document is controlled by the `\baselinestretch` macro, for example [here](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/latex/ltx-86.html). Setting `\baselinestretch` in the preamble does in fact change line spacing. When I redefine `\baselinestretch` inside the document however, the line spacing is unaffected.

It is clearly possible to change the line spacing mid-document, as [demonstrated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83855/change-line-spacing-inside-the-document/83856#83856) by the `setspace` package, but why does simply redefining `\baselinestretch` not do this?

---

As an example, I would expect the following code to have one paragraph of lorem ipsum at 1.5 spacing, followed by the same paragraph at 1.0 spacing, but both come out as 1.5 spaced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\baselinestretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\hrule
\def\baselinestretch{1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\baselinestretch` just sets the multiplier used at the next font selection, so you need `\selectfont`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\baselinestretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\hrule
\def\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: And it's better to use `\linespread{1.5}\selectfont`

Comment: What does `\linespread` do which makes it better to use?

Comment: @Brian not a lot, it leaves latex in a bit better state if you don't use \selectfont straight away but if you do it comes to the same thing, but perhaps looks more declarative rather than using the general `\renewcommand` (or especially looks better than dropping down to the primitive `\def`:-)