# How to add vertical space before a line in LaTeX?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I'm trying to define a new command similar to

```
\newcommand {\mainv} {\par\noindent\hspace*{0pt}\ignorespaces}
```

However, I want to have some negative preceding vertical space. I know that `\vspace` adds vertical space after the text. Is there a similar command that can add vertical space before the text?

The command that will provide the following output will be:

```
\main {This text is written using command main}
\mainv {This text is written using command mainv}
```

where `\main` is defined as

```
\newcommand {\main} {\par\noindent\hspace*{0pt}\ignorespaces}
```

[image: The following image in MS Word shows what I'm looking for:]

Comment: Could you provide an image of what you mean?

Comment: @Werner I added a sample text which is written in MS Word. The preceding space of second line is reduced.

Comment: Can you also show the command usage that would provide the required output?

Comment: @Werner Sure. It would be something like `\main {This text is written using command main}` `\mainv {This text is written using command mainv}`

Comment: How is the macro `\main` defined?

Comment: @Mico Sorry for the confusion. I updated the post.

Comment: @Mahdi: What `\documentclass` are you using? It could be that the document class defines `\parskip` to be non-zero, and that's the space that you're seeing.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `\hspace*{0pt}\ignorespaces` part of the macro(s)?

Comment: @Werner That's the default spacing, I wanted the \mainv to have a space less than the default. Willie's answer works for my problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Mico I don't really know. This is taken from another source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\main{\par\noindent\hspace*{0pt}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\mainV{\vspace{-10pt}\main}

\begin{document}

\main Some text
\main Some text
\main Some text
\mainV some other, overlapping text
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from the code above]

Answer (score 3):

It is not completely clear to me what you are trying to achieve and why do you want to overlap lines, so I’ll stick to the question “Is there a command that can add vertical space before a line of text?”.

The pdfTeX engine has a `\vadjust pre` primitive that can conveniently be used for this.  See the following MWE.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\vspacebeforeline[1]{%
    \ifvmode % if in vertical mode, act as "\vspace{#1}"
        \vskip #1
        \vskip \z@skip
    \else
        \@bsphack
        \vadjust pre {%
            \@restorepar
            \vskip #1
            \vskip \z@skip
        }%
        \@esphack
    \fi
}

\makeatother




\begin{document}

Here is some nonsensical text, written for the sole purpose of filling up at
least one line.  Well, after all I~think that two lines would be even better.
And now, we use our new command exactly here\vspacebeforeline{18pt plus 6pt 
minus 6pt}, followed by a few other words to end the test.

\vspacebeforeline{3pt}

It can be used in vertical mode, too.

\end{document}
```

This is the output it produces:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Learn something everyday :)

Comment: Thanks Gustavo. I'll try this solution later today, but I guess it does what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are trying to overlap lines, I would venture to guess you're looking for the variable `\baselineskip` or `\baselinestretch`? But you probably don't want to change those variables directly because other macros scale off of them.

> \baselineskip: A parameter that tells TeX the distance between baselines.

or `\linespread`

e.g. set line spread for next font change: `\linespread{1.5}\selectfont`

Otherwise, yeah, just manipulating the space around vertical boxes, `\vspace{<natural height> plus <stretching> minus <shrinking>}` is your tool.

## To get yourself on the right track

- [Why does changing \baselinestretch not change line spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241120/why-does-changing-baselinestretch-not-change-line-spacing)
- [Is \baselineskip automatically defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141268/is-baselineskip-automatically-defined)
- [Lengths and when to use them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/lengths-and-when-to-use-them) (my personal favorite)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. There is a lot of useful information in your answer. Sorry I can't up-vote yet.

Comment: @Mahdi No prob. Yea without a working example from you, it's a shot in the dark, but I see you're new here.