# How to Change vertical distance between lines?

Tags: spacing, setspace

I'am writing on my thesis and I want to change the vertical distance between the lines that i write. I tried it with doublespacing and setspace but nothing changed, can you help my guys? 
In my MWE the distance between the lines is like the size what i want to have, but in my whole file the distance is shorter. I don't know where my mistake is?
This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{graphicx}

 %\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone} %für den Baum
  \usepackage[rm={tabular, lining},sf={tabular, lining},tt={monowidth,       
   tabular, lining}]{cfr-lm}
   \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
  \usepackage[edges]{forest}
 \usetikzlibrary{fit}
  \usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
 \allowdisplaybreaks
 \usepackage{bm}%macht mathezeichen fett
 \usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
 \usepackage{courier}
  \usepackage[left=30mm,right=40mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm, includeheadfoot,      
 centering]{geometry}
 \usepackage{parskip}
 \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
 %\usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage[center]{caption2}
 \usepackage[flushmargin,bottom,hang]{footmisc}
 \usepackage{acronym}
 \usepackage[noxspace,final]{listofsymbols}
\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{hyperref} % hyperref für Fußnoten usw
  \hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=black,
      filecolor=black,
      citecolor = black,      
     urlcolor=black,
      }
\usepackage{lmodern} %Schriftart ändern
  \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %Schriftart geändert
 \usepackage{pgfplots} %von philipp
  \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
  \usepackage{verbatim}
  \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{parskip}


 \pagestyle{myheadings}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
 \setlength{\parskip}{0cm}
 \setlength{\footnotemargin}{1em}
  \opensymdef



   \setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
   \begin{document}


  Nachdem das Hybrid-Flexible-Flow Shop-Problem mit Lotstreaming Option in      
   Kapitel xxx in seinen theoretischen Grundzügen erläutert wurde, befasst  
   sich das folgende Kapitel mit der mathematischen Modellierung des Hybrid-
     Flexibel-Flow-Shop-Problem mit Lotstreaming Option als gemischt-
     ganzzahliges Problem.


       \end{document} code here
```

Hre a epicture how it is in my thesis

[image: In my thesis]

How can i change the vertical distance between my lines? `\setspace` or one and `\doublespacing`? Nothing works....

Comment: Employing `\spacing{2.5}` certainly changes the line spacing.  A value of `1` gives single spacing, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83855/change-line-spacing-inside-the-document>

Comment: Why overriding `onehalfspacing` with `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}`?

Answer (score 4):

You are overriding the `onehalfspacing` (or `doublespacing`) option to `setspace` by doing

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
```

Remove it.

On the other hand, your preamble is quite a mess. You load:

1. `cfr-lm`
2. `helvet`
3. `lmodern`

in this order and then say `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`; this way, only the last of those three packages is used and the other two do nothing at all.

It's quite strange to load `parskip` and then set the `\parskip` to zero.

The `caption2` package is obsolete and should not be used: `caption` is the right one. Also `fancyhdr` is loaded, but not employed.

I have grouped the packages in a more proper way and commented some of them. The `centering` option to `geometry` contradicts the other options, so I commented it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 

\usepackage[
  left=30mm,
  right=40mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=20mm,
  includeheadfoot,      
%  centering, %%% <--- what for?
]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[
  rm={tabular,lining},
  sf={tabular,lining},
  tt={monowidth,tabular,lining},
]{cfr-lm}
%\usepackage{lmodern} %Schriftart ändern
%\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
%\usepackage{courier}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}%macht mathezeichen fett
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
%\usepackage{parskip}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[flushmargin,bottom,hang]{footmisc}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{pgfplots} %von philipp
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[noxspace,final]{listofsymbols}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\usepackage{hyperref} % hyperref für Fußnoten usw
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  citecolor = black,      
  urlcolor=black,
}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

%%% Make my thesis as hard to read as possible
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1em}
\opensymdef


\begin{document}

\section{Formale Modellbeschreibung}

Nachdem das Hybrid-Flexible-Flow Shop-Problem mit Lotstreaming Option in      
Kapitel xxx in seinen theoretischen Grundzügen erläutert wurde, befasst  
sich das folgende Kapitel mit der mathematischen Modellierung des 
Hybrid-Flexibel-Flow-Shop-Problem mit Lotstreaming Option als 
gemischt-ganzzahliges Problem.

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output with `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}`   with  `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}`

Comment: vertical distance between the lines

Comment: You can use `\setstretch{}`. If you want to only affect a certain content you can use it with a group.

Comment: @egreg the problem is that i have mathematical and normal language and pictures in my thesis, so i used a lot of packages people told me to use. Iam not so familiar with latex. It is my first work with it and the university give me an latexexample which is almost obsolete and old.... but i have no better example to build my thesis... thank you very much for your help