# Maximise space with 6 pts in math mode multicols

Tags: math-mode

On the first page last column of this [Document](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bdsmhmntjxfd), the vertical spaces between each line is wider than the rest and I can't add anymore text to that column, else it will just spill over to the next page, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Hi. We don't like following external links, as they may be down at any moment. Please add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) here instead!

Answer (score 1):

Spacing in the final column appears in keeping with the other columns for me. Regardless, several ways of controlling line spacing are:

- Reduce text line spacing for the entire document by specifying `\linespread{x}` in the preamble where `x` is less than 1
- Change text line spacing locally with the `\setstretch{x}` command from the `setspace` package (see [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83856/172926))
- Changing the `\jot` length with, for example, `\setlength{\jot}{6pt}` (default `8pt`), which determines the spacing in a multi-line amsmath environment
- Changing the line spacing following a particular equation in a multi-line amsmath environment by using, for example, `\\[-2pt]` to end the equation line instead of just `\\`