# How can I reduce the space between lines in a list?

Tags: lists, indentation, itemize, enumitem

I would like to personalize my list, to make it more compact. In part I managed, in fact I was able to reduce the space between the item but the problem I have now is that when in the same item the sentence is indented the space is too much space between the lines, I had to put the spacing of my whole document set at 1.5 (`\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`) but in the list I would like it to be 1 ... Specifically, in the picture below, in the second item, I would like to reduce the space between the first and second line

Below is my code

```
begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-2ex]
        \item exterior orientation file (EO): it describes the position of the camera when the  images are acquired;
        \item interior orientation file (IO): it describes the internal geometry of a camera, i.e., the camera and distortion parameters;
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertical space in lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists)

Comment: It looks like you explicitely increased the line spacing (which I would deem bad typography). This line spacing also applies to lists, of course. While it can [easily be changed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83855/48973), I would consider changing the line spacing mid document absolutely awful typography. To really let us help you, please make your code snipped a minimal working example (MWE), i.e. something that anyone can run without any changes for testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't manipulate the low-level command `\baselinestretch` directly. I suggest you load the `setspace` package and issue the instruction `\setstretch{1.5}` instead. Next, load the `etoolbox` package and issue the instruction

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\par\medskip\setstretch{1.0}}
```

in the preamble.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,setspace,lipsum,etoolbox}
\setstretch{1.5}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\par\medskip\setstretch{1.0}}
\frenchspacing % optional
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2][1-5]
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item \lipsum[1][1-4]
  \item \lipsum[1][5-8]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2][1-5]
\end{document}
```