# fixate footer to have different linespacing inside the document

Tags: spacing, header-footer, line-spacing, footer

I want to vary my linespacing in my LaTeX document. I want the footer, headlines and other parts of the document to be at onehalfspacing, but the main text to be doublespacing.

My solution was to use `setspace` with `\doublespacing` in the text and also the footer to specify it for every text. Similar to this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542102

```
\documentclass[fontsize = 12pt]{scrreprt}       
\usepackage{lmodern}                    % for different font style
\usepackage{lipsum}                     % for dummy text
\usepackage{tabularx}                   % for tabulars
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % for tabular functions
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}           % for modifying footer
\clearpairofpagestyles                  % remove standard style (removes default pagenumbering)

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}   % change linespace to 2

% defining the footer
\newcommand{\footerON}
{                                                   
    \ifoot[                                                 % footer for even pages
    \onehalfspacing
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{0.79\textwidth}Xr}       % create tabular over textwidth
        \midrule                                            % horizontal line over footer
        A long title of my document which stretches over two lines created by KarateKlaus & &                   
        \thepage                                            % pagenumbering on the right 
    \end{tabularx}
    \doublespacing
    ]                                   
    {                                                       % same footer for odd pages
        \onehalfspacing
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{0.79\textwidth}Xr}
            \midrule
            A long title of my document which streches over two lines created by KarateKlaus & & 
            \thepage 
        \end{tabularx}
        \doublespacing
    }
}   
\newcommand{\footerOFF}{\ifoot[]{}}

\begin{document}
    
    \footerON
    
    \chapter{multiline chaptertitle to test the linespaceing}
        \doublespacing
        \lipsum[1-1]
        \par
        \onehalfspacing
    
    \section{multiline sectiontitle to test the linespaceing in a section}
        \doublespacing
        \lipsum[1-3]
        \par
        \onehalfspacing
    
\end{document}
```

The problem with this methode seems to be that the horizontal line over the footer isn't the same height through the document. When a paragraph continues at the next side, the whole footer moves down just so slightly.

Is there a way to fixate the footer or at least counter my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off topic: The comments in your code regarding `\ifoot` are wrong. The syntax of `\ifoot` is

`\ifoot[<content for page style plain.scrheadings>]{<content for page style scrheadings>}`

There is also a short version

`\ifoot*{<content for both page styles plain.scrheadings and scrheadings>}`

---

There is a spurious space before `\onehalfspacing` in your code. You have to comment these spaces:

```
\ifoot*{% <- removes spurious space!
  \onehalfspacing
  ...  
  \doublespacing
}
```

But you should remove `\onehalfspacing` and `\doublespacing` from `\ifoot`. Using

`\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\onehalfspacing}`

you will get the desired spacing for page header and footer.

```latex
\documentclass[fontsize = 12pt,
  headheight=24pt,footheight=61pt% avoids the warning regarding head height and foot height
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles% removes default header and footer content for both page styles plain.scrheadings and scrheadings

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\onehalfspacing}% header and footer use \onehalfspacing

% defining the footer
\newcommand{\footerON}
{%
  \ifoot*{% <- removes spurious space!
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{0.79\textwidth}>{\raggedleft}X}
    \midrule
    A long title of my document which stretches over two lines created by KarateKlaus &
    \pagemark
  \end{tabularx}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\footerOFF}{\ifoot*{}}

\begin{document}
\footerON
\chapter{multiline chaptertitle to test the linespaceing}
\doublespacing
\lipsum[1]
\par
\onehalfspacing

\section{multiline sectiontitle to test the linespaceing in a section}
\doublespacing
\lipsum[1-3]
\par
\onehalfspacing
\end{document}
```

[image]

But maybe you can use

```latex
\documentclass[fontsize = 12pt,
  headheight=24pt,footheight=61pt% avoids the warning regarding head height and foot height
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles% removes default header and footer content for both page styles plain.scrheadings and scrheadings

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}   % change linespace

\AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup}{\useonehalfspacing}% headings should use \onehalfspacing
\newcommand*\useonehalfspacing[1]{\onehalfspacing}

\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\onehalfspacing}% header and footer use \onehalfspacing

% defining the footer
\newcommand{\footerON}
{%
  \ifoot*{% <- removes spurious space!
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{0.79\textwidth}>{\raggedleft}X}
    \midrule
    A long title of my document which stretches over two lines created by KarateKlaus &
    \pagemark
  \end{tabularx}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\footerOFF}{\ifoot*{}}

\begin{document}
\footerON
\chapter{multiline chaptertitle to test the linespaceing}
\lipsum[1]

\section{multiline sectiontitle to test the linespaceing in a section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]