# Change line spacing along the document in memoir class

Tags: memoir, line-spacing

I'm using «memoir» class and I have to change the line-spacing in different paragraph.

I tried to resolve the problem like in [Change line spacing inside the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83855/change-line-spacing-inside-the-document) but the answer does not apply in «memoir» class, since in this class the environment "spacing" remains undefined.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

{\begin{spacing}{1.0}\color{blue}
\lipsum[2]\end{spacing}
}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 3.3.2 of the manual is devoted to this problem. First of all, `memoir` ignores `\usepackage{setspace}`, because it sets up its own methods.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\OnehalfSpacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{SingleSpace}\color{blue}
\lipsum[2]
\end{SingleSpace}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with `\DoubleSpacing` instead of `\OnehalfSpacing`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please read the `memoir` documentation, in particular section                                                                                                                                                               **3.3.2 Double spacing**. In your code change `{spacing}` to `{Spacing}` and don't use the `setspace` package.