# Change font size inside the document

Tags: fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change font size mid document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/how-to-change-font-size-mid-document)

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\begin{document}
\include{Chapter1}
\end{document}
```

I would change the font size from 12 to 10 in a page inside the document and not the entire document.  How can I do it please?