# Change font size in the middle of a document or for individual included .tex file

Tags: fontsize

I'm writing a lengthy project which needs to be in `12pt`, but my appendices make use of `\small` and `\tiny` commands which only align correctly in `10pt` since there is a large amount of numerical data in multiple columns across the pages (these get too squished together and overlap in any higher font size).

I have separate sections and `\include` those files, and wish only to set the appendix section in a smaller font. I reference to the appendix and it contains many figures so can't make it a separate document.

I'm trying to use `\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont` but it's not working. Sometimes it doesn't change anything, at the moment it makes the font slightly smaller but not `10pt` size.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\includeonly{intro,theory,appendix}

\begin{document}

\include{intro}
\include{theory} %...etc


{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont       %<---this doesn't work
\include{appendix}
}

\end{document}
```

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and self taught, so most of my help comes from googling and ending up here, but I'm really stuck at this one and the solutions to similar questions don't seem to work for me.

[This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/how-to-change-font-size-mid-document) makes the font size correct but seems to add the page margins twice in the appendix, so that the whole appendix text is too far down and too far to the right.

Comment: Try with `\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont` as the first line inside the file `appendix`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you add a sample of the contents of `appendix.tex`?

Comment: That should work although it would be better to use `\footnotesize` instead of `\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont ` as that sets up smaller math fonts etc as well. Please cut down your document to not include the earlier chapters, just some inline text, and have the smallest appendix that shows the problem and then we can test locally, you could also uplaod an image of your result (you'll need to remove the `!` from the image markup to make it a link if you do not have the rep to post images)