# Change base fontsize for rest of document

Tags: fontsize

There are already two questions regarding this *problem*:

- [Switching to different font size(s) locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15835/switching-to-different-font-sizes-locally)
- [Change font size in the middle of a document or for individual included .tex file [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98659/change-font-size-in-the-middle-of-a-document-or-for-individual-included-tex-fil)

The problem with the first approach is that it adds too much page margin and that the content of the Appendix is off.

The problem with the second approach (from the comments to the question) is that it only affects the font size of the normal text, not that of headings etc.

I'd like a solution like the first, but it should keep the page margins as they are.

> It should work with the standard document class `article`.
>
> Using additional packages is **not** a problem, but they shouldn't alter the defined style.

### Minimal Example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\begin{document}
  Normal sized text, headings, etc.
  \begin{appendices}
    Smaller sized text, headings, etc.
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the KOMA-classes it can be easily done:

```
\documentclass[
 a4paper,
 fontsize=12pt,
 parskip=half
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

{\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt} \lipsum[1] \small abc\par}

\lipsum[1] \small abc

\end{document}
```

Comment: Changed the document class to `scrartcl` but it immediately started throwing way too many errors and warnings. Plus I don't know if using that document class changes some formatting that was previously used together with `article` and isn't recognized anymore by the KOMA class.

Comment: Did you get errors with my example? Or did you simply try in a large document? That's not a good idea. Start in a small document. And yes: changing the class can change the formatting. So you will have to decide if it is worth the trouble.

Comment: The errors aren't related to your example. I need it within a huge document and can't start from scratch; therefore I'll need a solution that works without KOMA support. Upvoted your answer, but it's not my solution.