# How to Generally Increase the Size and Line Spacing of the Footnotes?

Tags: spacing, footnotes, fontsize

I think that the footnotes are generally a little too small, and I would like to increase their size globally (for the entire document). How do I go about doing this?

Moreover, I think that the spacing between footnotes, and the line spacing for footnotes generally, is too small. How can I configure these (*two different*) properties of footnotes?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}    

\makeatletter  
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\leftskip=0em\hskip-0em\@makefnmark#1}  
\makeatother  

\begin{document}  
Caesar non supra grammaticos\footnote{''even Caesar is not above grammar/grammarians.''}. Tu enim Caesar civitatem dare potes hominibus, verbis non potes.\footnote{This is going to be a longer footnote: ''Caesar, you can grant citizenship to men but not to words.''}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The default document classes define `\@footnotetext` to include a font switch `\footnotesize`. Here's a typical view on that:

[image]

You could use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch `\@footnotetext` and insert the appropriate font specifications as a replacement. Just add the following to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}% <cmd>
  {\footnotesize}% <search>
  {\scriptsize}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

[image]

The above replaces `\footnotesize` with the declaration/switch `\scriptsize` (you can pick your flavour). If you wish to space things out as well, use the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) to do something similar:

```
\usepackage{setspace,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{setspace,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}% <cmd>
  {\footnotesize}% <search>
  {\scriptsize\setstretch{1.5}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

[image]

For font size referencing, see [How to change font size mid document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4139/5764). For a `setspace` reference, see [Why is the `\linespread` factor as it is?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30073/5764).