# Changing Font Size globally via package

Tags: fontsize, package-writing

I'd like to write a package that performs the following tasks (it's essentially reformatting the document to make it suitable for being printed 2-pages-side-by-side on a printer):
- adjust the margins to make them smaller
- adjust the global fontsize of the document

I know how to do the first (adjusting margins), but am stumped on how to adjust the second. What I'd like is to have the same effect as specifying

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

at the beginning of the document. But I'd like to achieve this effect by calling a package.

I've looked at the question [How to change font size mid-document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/how-to-change-font-size-mid-document%20%22How%20to%20change%20font%20size%20mid-document?), but could not make it work, by trying

```
\input{size12.clo}
```

either in the pre-amble or in the main body of the document).

I'd like accomplish all of this without wrapping my document in any extra environments, etc.

I've also tried using the \fontsize command, to no effect (you can see my attempt in the bare bones package below).

Here are the MWE. First, the main document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % For filler text

\usepackage{double-duplex} % This is the package I'd like to use to alter the size---the target of my question here.

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

And then the package, which I've called double-duplex.sty

```
\ProvidesPackage{double-duplex}

\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont
```

Comment: `\fontsize{sizea}{sizeb}\selectfont` as quick and dirty solution

Comment: Tried that, both inside and outside the preamble. No joy. Is there more to using this solution than just including, say, \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont in the preamble?

Comment: You could store that command in your `sty` file, by loading it, the command will be applied. Another rather unsatisfactory way would be to redefine `\normalsize`

Comment: Even by putting the \fontsize etc. command into my package, I don't get the desired result. I think it MWE time, I've edited my original question to include it.

Comment: Yeah, had the arguments backwards. Sorry about that, edited it in the main post seconds later, but you were too quick for me.

Comment: @jon The quick-and-dirty solution using \AtBeginDocument{\fontsize etc. does a fairly good job, but at least on my configuration (pdflatex, texlive 2011) it only adjusts regular text. Text that is enclosed in {\large ...} is unaltered. It'd be great to have a solution without that limitation

Comment: In that case, I'd do it differently: `\newif\ifprinttwoside \printtwosidetrue \ifprinttwoside                         
\documentclass{article} \else \documentclass[12pt]{article} \fi` (note: default is `\printtwosidefalse`).  If you like, you can pass the `\newif\ifprinttwoside \printtwosidetrue` as part of the call to `latex`.

Comment: @jon: your solution just now looks like it assumes that I invoke the twoside option at some point---I don't really want to do that. I just want to have the regular options for the class call in the magnified version (except, of course, for the larger font).

Comment: Why don't you use a custom *class* with an option `duplex` which you can switch as required. Your class can then load `article` with the relevant options depending on the options you pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution: if you are using the default article class at 10 pt (default), you can copy the relevant parts of `size12.clo` into your `double-duplex.sty` and change everything to a `\renewcommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{double-duplex.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{double-duplex}
% REnewed from size12.clo
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xiipt{14.5}%
   \abovedisplayskip 12\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus7\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
\renewcommand\small{%
  \@setfontsize\small\@xipt{13.6}%
  \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@ 
  \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@ 
  \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini 
              \topsep 9\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus5\p@
              \parsep 4.5\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@ 
              \itemsep \parsep}%
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip }

\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
  \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@xpt\@xiipt 
  \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@ 
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
  \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
  \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini 
              \topsep 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
              \parsep 3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@ 
              \itemsep \parsep}%
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip }
\renewcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viiipt{9.5}}
\renewcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vipt\@viipt}
\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xivpt{18}}
\renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xviipt{22}}
\renewcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xxpt{25}}
\renewcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxvpt{30}}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For filler text

%\usepackage{double-duplex} 

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}
\lipsum*[1-3]%
\footnote{\lipsum[4]}

\end{document}
```

Uncomment `\usepackage{double-duplex}` to 'switch' to 12 pt.

The following, however, would be my choice:

```
\newif\ifxiipt
% \xiipttrue
\ifxiipt
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\else
  \documentclass{article}
\fi

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\ifxiipt
  \geometry{<smaller margin settings>}
\else
  \geometry{<normal margin settings>}
\fi
\usepackage{lipsum} % For filler text

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}
\lipsum*[1-3]%
\footnote{\lipsum[4]}
\end{document}
```

To effect the same changes, simply uncomment the `\xiipttrue`.  (The reason I prefer this solution is that it will probably make it easier to do different things for the bigger-font-smaller-margins version or the normal version beside just changing the margins or the font size.)