# Change in font size from slide to slide

Tags: beamer, fontsize

Is it possible, that one of my slide in `beamer` is  11 pt    and I want 10 pt font in other slide?

Comment: Yes. Does this hold for everything on the frame, including the frame title, and footer, or just the "internal content" of the frame?

Comment: Internal content sir

Comment: still one sentence questions with no example?

Comment: Again sorry sir. But sir I dont want to cheat. You know if i upload the code , you great people will edit it and it will be copied back. I just want to take an idea from you people and edit it on my own

Comment: @Ahmad It makes it _much_ harder to answer if you don't provide a test document. Look at werner's answer, he had to write a complete document to test the answer,  you should have provided that.

Comment: Ok sir. I got it. From next time , I will provide you the material. Thanks sir.

Comment: and please, don't call me sir:-) If you want to reply to someone use the `@` otherwise they probably will not see it.

Answer (score 13):

You can switch to a different font size outside the `frame`, and specify the scope using a group:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a title 11pt}
  Here is some content on the slide
  \[
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \]
  Some more content
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\small% \small in 11pt base font is 10pt
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a title 10pt}
  Here is some content on the slide
  \[
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \]
  Some more content
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a title 11pt}
  Here is some content on the slide
  \[
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \]
  Some more content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Above I've specified `\small`, which defaults to 10pt font under an 11pt document class option.

Since each of the frame components use template-specific settings, they need to be adjusted separately. However, the above technique is an easy one to update the internal frame content only.

Comment: This solution is very similar in nature to what is suggested in [How to change font size mid document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4139/5764)

Comment: Sadly this affects only the main text in the frame. If you have nested `itemize` lists, for example, the nested items are not affected.