# how make a equation a little smaller

Tags: equations, size, multline

how I can make a little the following equation smaller?

```
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{\psi_{m}}=\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}\exp(\frac{-2\pi imk}{n})}}=\dfrac{1}{\langle V_{m},c \rangle+i\langle U_{m},c\rangle}
=\dfrac{\langle V_{m},c \rangle-i\langle U_{m},c\rangle}{\langle V_{m},c \rangle^{2}+\langle U_{m},c\rangle^{2}} 
\end{equation}
```

I tried to split it by useing multline but it doesn't give a number to this term.

Comment: `multline` does give equation number. Please extend your sniplet to a real example, as the code sits here it cannot even be compiled because of the two blank lines.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/how-to-change-font-size-mid-document

Comment: @HumaidAlkalbani Changing font size to accommodate a long equation should be used only as last resort. And even then it shouldn't be used `:-)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

with use of the `nccmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\medmath{  % <--- reduce equation size for about 20 %
\frac{1}{\psi_{m}}
    =\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}\exp\Bigl(\mfrac{-2\pi imk}{n}\Bigr)}
    =\frac{1}{\langle V_{m},c \rangle+i\langle U_{m},c\rangle}
    =\frac{\langle V_{m},c \rangle-i\langle U_{m},c\rangle}{\langle V_{m},c \rangle^{2}+\langle U_{m},c\rangle^{2}}
                        }
\end{equation}
or without \verb+\limits+ at \verb+\sum+, i.e. sumation limits are in inline mode:
\begin{equation}\medmath{
\frac{1}{\psi_{m}}
    =\frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}\exp\Bigl(\mfrac{-2\pi imk}{n}\Bigr)}
    =\frac{1}{\langle V_{m},c \rangle+i\langle U_{m},c\rangle}
    =\frac{\langle V_{m},c \rangle-i\langle U_{m},c\rangle}{\langle V_{m},c \rangle^{2}+\langle U_{m},c\rangle^{2}}
                        }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
added is a case where summation limits consider @Mico comment below.

Comment: +1 for `\medmath`. Please don't use `\sum\limits`, though.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! Using `\sum\limits` make fraction a bit shorter and it is only a little bit higher than argument of `\exp`. To me not look so bad :-). Of course, OP can freely remove `\limits`. I will add this option asap.

Answer (score 11):

I suggest that you employ a `split` environment inside the `equation` environment, split the math material across three lines, and use the `=` symbols as the alignment points.

For extra legibility, I would also replace `\exp(\frac{-2\pi imk}{n})` with `\exp(-2\pi imk/n)`, i.e., use inline-fraction notation in the denominator term of the first fraction expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "split" environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{\psi_{m}}
&=\frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}\exp(-2\pi imk/n)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\langle V_{m},c\rangle + i\langle U_{m},c\rangle}\\[1ex]
&=\frac{\langle V_{m},c\rangle    - i\langle U_{m},c\rangle}%
       {\langle V_{m},c\rangle^{2}+  \langle U_{m},c\rangle^{2}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `dfrac` is, so I replaced it by `frac` and simply used an `eqnarray` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{\psi_{m}} &=&\frac{1}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}
\exp\left(\frac{-2\pi imk}{n}\right)} \nonumber \\
&=& \frac{1}{\langle V_{m},c \rangle+i\langle U_{m},c\rangle} \nonumber \\[7pt]
&=& \frac{\langle V_{m},c \rangle-i\langle U_{m},c\rangle
         }{\langle V_{m},c \rangle^{2}+\langle U_{m},c\rangle^{2}} 
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\dfrac` is similar to `{\displaystyle\frac ...}`. Also, why are you still using `eqnarray`? You should have a read of [`eqnarray` vs `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764).

Comment: I did not know that about eqnarray; I learned to use it some 30 years ago and never looked back. Sorry - and thanks for the info.