# Scale tt font starting from current page

Tags: fontsize

My goal is to scale the tt font down starting someplace in the document.
I achieved it by using `\fontsize{7pt}{11pt}\selectfont`:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline,manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}


This is a normal text. \large{Large text}

\ttfamily
This is a tt family text. \large{Large text}

\fontsize{7pt}{11pt}\selectfont
This is a tt family text. \large{Large text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that `\large` is still the same size as before.

How I scale everything?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to change font size mid document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4139)

Comment: Not directly related but \large doesn't take an argument,  that is a switch.

Comment: As long as you always use tt by way of a `\texttt{}` syntax, rather than a `\ttfamily` syntax, you could define a new command `\newcommand\smalltt[1]{\texttt{\small#1}}`, where I chose `\small` as the desired size, but could be changed to `\footnotesize`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's the motivation for this. Anyway…

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline,manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{smallercmtt}{\hyphenchar\font-1 }
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{smallercmtt}{m}{n}{
        <-9>    s*[0.7] ectt0800
        <9-10>  s*[0.7] ectt0900
        <10-12> s*[0.7] ectt1000
        <12-17> s*[0.7] ectt1200
        <17->   s*[0.7] ectt1728
      }{}


\begin{document}

\section{Test}

This is a normal text. {\Large Large text}

\texttt{This is a tt family text. {\Large Large text}}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{smallercmtt}
\texttt{This is a tt family text. {\Large Large text}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, note that `\large`, like the other size changing commands, does not take an argument but is a declaration whose effect is permanent (obeying the standard scoping rules).

In the example I use `\Large` just to better show the difference in size.

Answer (score 0):

With `fontspec` package and TTF/OTF fonts under xelatex/lualatex, the `Scale=` option can be used:

[image: scaled font]

MWE

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline,manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}


\begin{document}

\section{Test}
This is a normal text. {\Large Large text} {\tiny Tiny text}


\sffamily
This is a sf family text. {\Large Large text} {\tiny Tiny text}

\ttfamily
This is a tt family text. {\Large Large text} {\tiny Tiny text}


Scaled:
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}[Scale=0.4]
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}[Scale=0.4]
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}[Scale=0.4]

\section{Scaled Test}

\rmfamily
This is a normal text. {\Large Large text} {\tiny Tiny text}


\sffamily
This is a sf family text. {\Large Large text} {\tiny Tiny text}

\ttfamily
This is a tt family text. {\Large Large text} {\tiny Tiny text}

\end{document}
```